# Update values on parse

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

Is there a way to update a number on parse not just by replacing it or creating a new object id then deleting the old one but by actually incrementing the value from the stored value on parse and the new value being added to it. Ie. 
On parse: Correct = 5 ; On app: Correct = 10 ; new value on parse: 15

This is my code but it just creates a new object id with the new values every time...

```
func saveScoresOnParse() {
    scores["Right"] = rightAnswers
    scores["Wrong"] = wrongAnswers
    scores["Skipped"] = skippedQuestions
    scores["User"] = PFUser.currentUser()
    scores.saveInBackground()
}
```

On parse:
[image: on parse]

I want the values to be added up and as well as only have one objectid for each one.

Comment: Use '– incrementKey:byAmount:'

Comment: How do I use that? @PowHu

Comment: https://www.parse.com/docs/ios/guide#objects-counters

Answer (score 0):

```
let scoreQuery = PFQuery(className: "Scores")
scoreQuery.whereKey("user", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!)
scoreQuery.getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock { (object, error) -> Void in
    if error == nil {
        if let scores = object {
        scores["Right"] = rightAnswers
        scores["Wrong"] = wrongAnswers
        scores["Skipped"] = skippedQuestions
        scores.saveInBackground()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I already tried this. This updates the value by the current amount of the variable, i.e. if the saved score on parse was five and my new score to be saved is 6 the new saved score on parse will be 11 and not 6.

Comment: Oh, what you want to do it query the scores to find the one with the user. Then you can update this in the completion block. I'll update the code in a bit.